# ParseException - mismatched input in subquery source - error in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am running the next query in Hive:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  (
   SELECT * 
   FROM 
   (SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count_p_id FROM palladion GROUP BY id) a, 
   (SELECT cid, COUNT(*) AS count_q_cid FROM operations GROUP BY cid) b 
   WHERE a.id=b.cid
  ) 
WHERE count_p_id < count_q_cid;
```

I keep getting the error like

```
 ParseException line 1:103 mismatched input ',' expecting ) near 'a' in subquery source
```

What is the problem with the code? I can't see any.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit join notation is supported starting with Hive 0.13.0. This allows the FROM clause to join a comma-separated list of tables, omitting the JOIN keyword. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

I hope you are using < 0.13.0 version . If your hive version is < 0.13.0

Try this : you have to use JOIN - ON , not Comma - WHERE

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  (
   SELECT * 
   FROM 
   (SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count_p_id FROM palladion GROUP BY id) a JOIN 
   (SELECT cid, COUNT(*) AS count_q_cid FROM operations GROUP BY cid) b 
   ON  a.id=b.cid
  ) 
WHERE count_p_id < count_q_cid;
```

Comment: Yes, it turns out we are using 0.10.0. The explicit join syntax works. Thank you!